# sort line by last name and in order

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, sorting, bluej

Ok so I have this code so far that sorts by job position, now It also needs to be sort by last name and in alphabetical order. Ive managed to make it by sort by position then give the average salary and total.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class faculty {

    private static final String ASSISTANT = "assistant";
    private static final String ASSOCIATE = "associate";
    private static final String FULL = "full";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileInputStream filestream;
        BufferedReader reader;
        PrintWriter writer;
        String line;

        double totalAssistant = 0;
        double totalAssociate = 0;
        double totalFull = 0;

        try {
            filestream = new FileInputStream("Faculty List.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(filestream));
            writer = new PrintWriter("test.txt");

            List<String> assistantList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> associateList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> fullList = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] split = line.split(" ");

                double value = Double.parseDouble(split[split.length - 1]);

                String type = split[split.length - 2];

                if (ASSISTANT.equals(type)) {
                    assistantList.add(line);

                } else if (ASSOCIATE.equals(type)) {
                    totalAssociate += value;
                    associateList.add(line);

                } else if (FULL.equals(type)) {
                    totalFull += value;
                    fullList.add(line);
                }
            }

            writeInFileOutput(writer, totalAssistant, assistantList);
            writeInFileOutput(writer, totalAssociate, associateList);
            writeInFileOutput(writer, totalFull, fullList);

            reader.close();

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        } finally {
            reader = null;
            filestream = null;
            writer = null;
        }

    }

    private static void writeInFileOutput(PrintWriter writer, double totalSalary, List<String> listLines) {
        for (String assistant : listLines) {
            writer.append(assistant).append("\n");
        }

        writer.append("-------\n");
        writer.append("Total Salary:$").append(String.valueOf(totalSalary)).append("\n");
        writer.append("Average Salary: $")
                        .append(String.valueOf(totalSalary / listLines.size())).append(" \n\n");
    }

}
```

Output

```
Pablo Bailey EDUC associate 68757.00
Lonnie Williamson GENS associate 134777.00
Raymond Page EDUC associate 120150.00
Wallace Fitzgerald BUSN associate 40889.00
Juana Robbins SOBL associate 93669.00
Steven Hall SOBL associate 117532.00
Melissa Davis EDUC associate 132186.00
Karla Valdez BUSN associate 16385.00
Melba Luna HLTH associate 70358.00
Sonja Washington HLTH associate 59302.00
Julio Diaz HLTH associate 102641.00
Virgil Briggs PAC associate 40936.00
Terrell Sherman EDUC associate 161595.00
Jorge Scott CSIS associate 124175.00
Tanya Duncan BUSN associate 178894.00
Troy Cannon BUSN associate 58890.00 
------- 
 Total Salary: $3645049.0
 Average Salary: $104144.25714285714
```

that's what my current output is, its sorted by rank. I now have to add to the list sort by last name first followed by first name alphabetically.this is just a small sample of the output cause the text file is pretty long.
The new lines can be added to the output.

Comment: Try not to encode data in Strings; define specific classes instead.  This way, you can have a list of, say, ´Professor´ objects that has givenName, familyName, type, salary, etc.  Have your `Professor` class implement `Comparable`, to make sorting easy. Then you can just define a comparator to handle the sorting.

Comment: Do you want to do a compound sort (by department AND name)?

Comment: Put every line to specific object as @SteveChaloner said and then you can sort with interface Comparable

Comment: I can't make out what the ordering is in the desired output - it doesn't seem to be alphabetical on any component of the name.  Are you showing desired output, or actual current output?

Comment: @SteveChaloner Sorry, that was probably my fault :P

Comment: I made a mistake, that's what my current output is, its sorted by rank. I now have to add to the list sort by last name first followed by first name alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

I would make your stuff much more object oriented. So this means: introduce a new object employee that has some fields like following example:

```
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String familyName;
    private String department;
    private Enum jobPosition;
    private double salary;

    // Put constructor and some getters and setters for your field here
}

public enum JobPosition {
    assistant,
    associate,
    full
}
```

When reading your input, split into the fields you need to create your employee and create 1 list with all your employees. Because you now have objects instead of a String containing multiple properties of one employee you can easily sort your objects on each property you want.

Comment: Okay, that's a start, but doesn't answer the question of how to sort it...not that I'm sure how the OP wants it sorted exactly...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Aster's approach, and then either make Employee implement `Comparable<Employee>`, or make a `Comparator<Employee>`.

### With `Comparable<Employee>`

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e) {
        int deptResult = this.department.compareToIgnoreCase(e.department);
        if (deptResult != 0) {
            return deptResult;
        }

        familyNameResult = this.familyName.compareToIgnoreCase(e.familyName);
        if (familyNameResult != 0) {
            return familyNameResult;
        }

        return this.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(e.firstName);
    }
}
```

### With `Comparator<Employee>`

```
public class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        int deptResult = e1.getDepartment().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getDepartment());
        if (deptResult != 0) {
            return deptResult;
        }

        familyNameResult = e1.getFamilyName().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getFamilyName());
        if (familyNameResult != 0) {
            return familyNameResult;
        }

        return e1.getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(e2.getFirstName());
    }
}
```